# python re.sub with re.search not working as expected

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to generate output file name and path using timestamp. All the parts works as expected, but re.sub is not giving me the result I want. What I'm doing wrong here?

```
>>> a = r'\output\End-of-Day\{%Y\%m\%d\UINVDEFF securities %m.%d.%Y}.xlsx'
>>> b = re.search(r'(?P<timestamp>\{[^}]*(%[A-Za-z])[^{]*\})', a)
>>> b.group('timestamp')
'{%Y\\%m\\%d\\UINVDEFF securities %m.%d.%Y}'

>>> now
datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 18, 11, 43, 47, 55000)

>>> now.strftime(b.group('timestamp'))[1:-1]
'2014\\08\\18\\UINVDEFF securities 08.18.2014'

>>> re.sub(b.group('timestamp'), now.strftime(b.group('timestamp'))[1:-1], a)
'\\output\\End-of-Day\\{%Y\\%m\\%d\\UINVDEFF securities %m.%d.%Y}.xlsx'
```

Expecting '\output\End-of-Day\2014\08\18\UINVDEFF securities 08.18.2014.xlsx'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) call is interpreting its first argument as a regex pattern:

```
{%Y\\%m\\%d\\UINVDEFF securities %m.%d.%Y}
```

When you just want to replace a substring with another in a string use [`string.replace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace):

```
a.replace(b.group('timestamp'), now.strftime(b.group('timestamp'))[1:-1])
```